# Can you help me with this nginx configurtation to get it working with a domain in https?

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, networking, dns

Setup is :
VPS Server with IP lets say 5.5.5.5
Domain : example.com
Docker compose with db, backend and frontend

The front end is written in Vue.js

I set up the domain DNS as the following :
A host:* ip: 5.5.5.5 ttl: 300
A host:@ ip: 5.5.5.5 ttl: 300
CNAME alias:www points at: example.com ttl:300
Dockerfile for the frontend

```
FROM node:latest as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx as production-stage
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./ssl/certs/ /etc/nginx/ssl/
COPY ./example.com /etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com
```

Now the NGINX conf inside the dockerfile:

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
      root   /app;
      index  index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
}
```

And example.com looks like this

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     example.com default_server;
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        expires off;
        return  301     https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com;
        client_max_body_size 32M;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";

        ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.pem;

  root "/usr/share/nginx/html";
  index index.html index.htm index.php; 
}
```

and in the server I changed etc/hosts with the following line:

```
192.168.1.23 example.com
```

How can I get it to work, it's almost done production ready. Just this conf is blocking me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Is your port of nginx docker both `443` and `80` exposed?

Comment: @whoami I'm just getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in the browser. The docker compose has 443 exposed and 80 too.. I have some issue in this conf but as I'm not experienced with nginx and is my first time I messed up something for sure..

Comment: so what you are saying is, the connection to nginx via the host machine itself is not working as expected? Also, what is the output when you try to access the service from inside the docker itself?

Comment: The api works from outside, the problem is only the nginx docker conf, as the db and api are working well, the nginx from outside gives err connection refused and same from the host machine with curl

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, nginx from inside the docker machine works as expcted, but when you try to access the same endpoint from host machine (where docker is hosted) gives error and same from outside the hostmachine as well? The entry for `/etc/hosts` is on your host machine or inside the nginx docker container?

Comment: @whoami in the host machine